# Gamma function grows large with Re(z)

Tags: gamma-function

How would you show that the Gamma function gets large in absolute value for z with large real part using just Euler's integral form defined as the following?

$\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt, Re(z)>0$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.